# No LDPI icon in the latest update of Eclipse Juno ADT

Tags: android, adt, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I updated to the latest version of Eclipse Juno and I have the Android ADT on it.

When I start a new project, it doesn't give the LDPI icon anymore, and the `drawable-ldpi` folder is empty.

What is the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm maybe they're fasing out ldpi slowly since less and less devices have it

Comment: It's not really a problem. It's just that the amount of LDPI devices that are available and used has declined to the point that Google/Android feels that the LDPI folder isn't relevant anymore.

Comment: but can I still work with that? I have a phone with LDPI!

Comment: Yup! You can still use that folder and devices that are LDPI will still utilize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only 10% of the devices are ldpi and this number is decreasing over time. Source: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

It is not **required** to have images for all the densities, only one is enough. The system will scale it up/down when needed. So the best approach is to have images for the highest density supported (xhdpi or xxhdpi).

I personally only use **xhdpi** images!